# Is C# DateTimeKind.Local referring to the computer or the business object?

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm writing a program handling the transcript of [US Airways Flight 1549](https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/US_Airways_Flight_1549), which starts at 15:05:34 the 15th of January 2009 local time.

I'm going to store the time in an DateTime variable, but am confused about the `DateTimeKind.Local` parameter.

If i store the time like below...

```
var startTime = new DateTime(2009, 1, 15, 15, 5, 34, DateTimeKind.Local);
```

... am I saying that the time starts 15:05 local time for the plane, i.e US Eastern Time, or local time for the computer running the program, i.e Swedish Standard Time?

Comment: The code has no way of knowing the context of what you're *using* this `DateTime` for, so it is for the system or process. The problem, though, is that it is *you* that is also writing the code that will use this value, which means it is probably up to you to determine what it means.

Comment: It means its local for the current locale for the calling thread.

Comment: It reflects the time of the computer, running the program.

Comment: Having said that you might want to look at NodaTime instead if you're concerned about things like this. The built-in DateTime types and time zone support and so on is rather inadequate in most cases. This library has a much clearer distinction between date and time values that are bound to a timezone vs. the ones that are not.

Comment: The text of your first paragraph, to me, means that the "local time" here relates to what "local" means to the plane at that time, where was that plane? In .NET, the "Local" kind of DateTime is just a flag that is used when dealing with to/from UTC conversions or similar to determine if this conversion is necessary or not, but as I said above, this is not enough to correctly handle these kinds of things. Instead, for instance with NodaTime, you could say that the time is "15:05:34 15th of January 2009 *in a specific time zone*".

Answer (score 5):

`DateTimeKind.Local` describes a DateTime as local to the running thread's locale, in this case your system's clock time. The built in DateTime is usually seen as a mistake by a lot of people because it's fairly inadequate. A library might give you more success.